# How to assign multiple variables to different value using 'for loop' in js

Tags: javascript

I was trying to assign **multiple variables** that i stored in an array to different variables that i stored in an array using the **for loop**. Here is what i have tried but didn't get my wanted result. Instead it changed the variable array to the contents in the other array.

```
let varOne, varTwo, varThree;

let varArray = [varOne, varTwo, varThree]
let valueArray = ['value-one', 'value-two', 
'value-three']

for (let i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
    varArray[i] = valueArray[i]
}
```

Comment: You can’t make an array of variables like that. Maybe reconsider your data structure.

Comment: so there's no way?

Comment: you are using array which is the same thing just directly assign value in array and access it with index, why you want to use thi short of structure , or else use ```javascript object```, it contains key value.

Comment: No practical way, unless you choose to make globals and access them as properties… But you most likely do not need that nor is it a good idea. Consider using an object instead.

Comment: pls can i get an example

Comment: This looks very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I think you should explain what problem you're trying to solve with this.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. Variables can't be modified like this. You just created a copy.

Comment: yh! that's what happened

Answer (score 2):

I not really understand what do you want to solve, but with destructuring an array you can assing values to multiple variables.

```js
let [varOne, varTwo, varThree] = ['value-one', 'value-two', 
'value-three'];

console.log(varOne, varTwo, varThree);
```

Or you cam map all the arrays into key-value pairs of an object.

```js
let varArray = ["varOne", "varTwo", "varThree"]
let valueArray = ['value-one', 'value-two', 
'value-three']

let res = {};
varArray.forEach((key, i)=> {
  res[key] = valueArray[i];
});

console.log(res);

// or in an array of object with map...
let res2 = varArray.map((key, i)=>{
    return {[key]: valueArray[i]};
  }
);

console.log(res2);
```

Comment: what if the code is very much and i want to assign them faster and easier?

Answer (score 0):

- Use `objects`

```js
let data={
 varOne:"value-one",
 varTwo:"value-two",
 varThree:"value-thress"
}
```